# Enabling a specific UITextField if another UITextField has a certain value

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have two `UITextField`s, `cDiseasePicker` and `optionalLMS`.

My `cDiseasePicker` uses a `UIPickerView` as input, with the options "No", "Yes, 1VD", "Yes, 2VD", and "Yes, 3VD".

If the user chooses "No", then `optionalLMS` should be greyed out/user interaction disabled. Otherwise, they should be allowed to edit it.

I've tried adding

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if cDiseasePicker.text == "Yes, 1VD" || cDiseasePicker.text == "Yes, 2VD" || cDiseasePicker.text == "Yes, 3VD" {
        optionalLMSText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        print("true cdisease")
    } else if cDiseasePicker.text == "No" {
        optionalLMSText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        print("false cdisease")
    }
}
```

But this seems to have no effect, and nothing is printed to the console.
This is my class declaration, if that makes a difference:

`class NewRecord: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate`

Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm still fairly new to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a `UIPickerView` as input, you should look at your picker view `didSelectRow` (which I guess you are using to populate your `cDiseasePicker` textfield) to configure the other textfield to your liking.

If I understand correctly the key information you need is that `textFieldDidEndEditing` method is called when the text field is no longer the first responder, not when the text changes.

Comment: didSelectRow worked perfectly, using the "if row == 0 { disable field } else { enable }". Thanks!